# Configuration and searching for Solr gettingstarted collection

Tags: solr

I'm going through Solr Quick Start (version 6.2.0), which creates gettingstarted collection and then ingests docs/ folder, but cannot find more explanation about these two questions.
First, collection is created with this line from console:

```
Creating new collection 'gettingstarted' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=gettingstarted&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=gettingstarted
```

Where are schema and solrconfig.xml files for this collection?

And after documents are ingested, there are 4405 of them in index, all with title field. But when enter in q input field title:Solr, get this response

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"zkConnected":true,
"status":0,
"QTime":63,
"params":{
  "q":"title:Solr",
  "indent":"on",
  "wt":"json",
  "_":"1480494738956"}},
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
}}
```

No documents are found, doesn't matter what is entered for title. Is it possible to search index by words in their title field?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the field type used for the field title?

Comment: From Admin UI it can be read as org.apache.solr.schema.StrField.
But, what I also want to find is which schema is connected with gettingstarted collection and how, to see these kind of information from there.

Comment: Go to the solr page...select the collection...click on the Files option... You can see the schema file there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using SolrCloud example. In which case, the configuration is loaded into Zookeeper. So, the live version is not on the filesystem, as it would be with non-cloud examples. You can look at that via Admin UI instead.

If you just want to see the bootstrapped configuration, it is located in server/solr/configsets/ and the specific configuration depends what you chose when creating the example.

Comment: That explains it. I found in one configset definition for title field, it's <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>. As I understood "text_general" fields should be tokenized, still don't know why searching for single words in it doesn't return any results.

Comment: This seems like a completely separate question, but quickly the Admin UI has an Analysis page that allows you to see how the text is parsed and how it is matched. Also enabling debug will show you which *processed* tokens are being matched against which fields.

Answer (score 0):

Config files will be in `/server/solr/gettingstarted/conf`

whenever you create new collection a folder with collection name is created inside server/solr/  inside that created folder there will be conf folder which contains config files(schema.xml, solrconfig.xml,etc) and data folder which contains index.

You should commit after you index documents into collection.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no server/solr/gettingstarted folder. And it is committed, *:* query returns all the documents. Still, query for any specific field returns no results.

Comment: how `title` field and its definition is defined in schema.xml file